# How to evaluate and compare regression models with limited number of observations in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I have a data frame with very limited number of observatons like the following and I want to run and compare a few regression models. I believe that any machine learning approaches would not make sense for my data and so, I have implemented linear models like the following.

```
p1<-c(0,0,25.41,43.78,30, 42.7,0,32.97,5.68,0,0,0,0,20.54,0,1.08,0,14.59,42.16,48.65,27.03, 0,61.08,1.62,2.7,0)
p2<-c(3,18,18,18,15,22,18,15,11,15,13, 13,12,15, 19,19,15, 18,22,22,22, 10,22,22,10,10)
p3<-c(2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1, 1, 3,3,3,2,2,1,3,3, 3,3,1,3,1,3,1)
p4<-c(5,4,1,2,1,3,3, 5,3,4,4,4,4,3,5,4, 4,4,3,2, 2,4,4, 2,3,2)
parameter<-c(0.601963475137328,4.48137286321025,7.09415223753352,7.01472719563573,6.12173889271508,6.69690226364833,3.22507854814473,7.07756354762698,6.15970151554205,1.57156302924526,0.075483589130117,6.62377068243363, 4.01693733556001,6.4483402513065,5.64141853140934,0.533091684904163,3.14673295448278,7.72501457089995,8.35763454067238,7.52799262640998,7.37015171551868,4.03988161821947, 9.31234562504067,1.79203438810106,5.04912946132768,5.00059034543363)
mydata<-data.frame(p1,p2,p3,p4,parameter)

m_control= trainControl(method="cv", number=3,savePredictions = TRUE)
in_train= createDataPartition(mydata$parameter, p=.66, list=FALSE) 
train_st=mydata[in_train,]
test_st=mydata[-in_train,] 
library(caret)
library(arm)
library(mboost)

#MODELS
set.seed(5894) 
mlr_st71 = train(parameter~ .,
                 data=train_st,method="lm",metric="Rsquared",trControl=m_control)

mlr_st72 = train(parameter~ .,
                 data=train_st,method="glmboost",metric="Rsquared",trControl=m_control)

mlr_st73 = train(parameter~ .,
                 data=train_st,method="bayesglm",metric="Rsquared",trControl=m_control)

mlr_st74 = train(parameter~ .,
                 data=train_st,method="glmStepAIC",metric="Rsquared",trControl=m_control)
```

As it is the first time I use such a small dataset 9I feel a bit uncomfortable), I would like to ask:

1. are these methods apropriate for the size of my dataset?

2 what is the best way to compare these models? (does the size of the data matters here?)

Comment: In what way do you with to "compare" the models?  You are applying four nominally different models, which implies four different conceptions of the data and the analytical objectives.  You need to include some information that one could use for evaluating the suitability of these models for your objectives.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your comment. I am not sure what you mean, but what I mean is to find/ plot each model's performance, so basically choose the model which best predict my parameter. That is my point with comparison. Am I wrong with this explaination?

Comment: That's not an appropriate way to choose models in most cases. One issue is that with small datasets, the choice of model can strongly influence the results.  You must select a model that reflects your assumptions and prior knowledge about the statistical behavior of the data.  A second issue, equally important, is that to compare results you need a quantitative way to measure their performance.  Each of your models implicitly adopts a potentially *different* relevant measure. (It turns out that the default settings in these functions are fairly compatible, but this is still a general concern.)